# Disable soft input for actionbar search view

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

Is it possible to completely disable the soft input keyboard for actionbar search view? I am showing a custom keyboard when the search view is tapped by setting the window's `SoftInputMode` to `AlwaysHidden` and hiding the default keyboard with `InputMethodManager's` `HideSoftInputFromWindow` method. But when the search view is in focus and I try to pull down the notification drawer and release it I get the default keyboard + the custom keyboard which is weird. Have anyone come across similar situation like this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can hide keyboard every time when search field gets the focus. You can set your text by setText. In this case soft keyboard won't be shown.

Here's interesting information which may help you: http://tech.leolink.net/2014/02/a-hack-to-catch-soft-keyboard-showhide.html